# Passing function to another class like Dart

Tags: java, android

I need to pass a function to another class and run that method in the second class with Java like Dart. In Dart, you can create a method like this:

```dart
void methodName(){

}

new OtherClass(methodName);

class OtherClass(){

    Function _methodName;
    
    OtherClass(Function methodName){
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

}
```

You can run the method just called in the OtherClass.

How can I do this in Java?

I tried passing Void, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java there is no methods not related to class. Here some examples how to pass references in Java whether static or not:

```
class OtherClass{

    Function<String, Integer> methodName;
    Consumer<String> consumer;
    Function<String, Integer> nonStatFunc;

    OtherClass(Function<String, Integer> methodName, Consumer<String> consumer){
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public OtherClass(Function<String, Integer> nonStatFunc) {

        this.nonStatFunc = nonStatFunc;
    }
    
}


class SomeClass{

    int a;

    public static void someConsumer(String x){
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static Integer someFunction(String o) {
        return Integer.parseInt(o);
    }

    public Integer nonStatFunc(String o){
        return Integer.parseInt(o) + a;
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass(SomeClass::someFunction, SomeClass::someConsumer);
        SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
        OtherClass otherClass1 = new OtherClass(instance::nonStatFunc);
    }
}
```

Take a look at `package java.util.function.*` it contains mostly all necessary contracts. If there is no suitable you made your own @FunctionalInterface. https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of classes which can be used as Function.

Check the package of jdk: `java.util.function`.

In jdk8, functional interfaces were introduced.

[java.util.function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8BAx.png)